How to debounce a server action when combining it with useOptimistic?
So I'm trying to update a quantity counter optimistically when you click the increment or decrement buttons. This part works fine with useOptimistic, however I don't want the server action to get executed for every quick click on those increment/decrement buttons. I want to debounce the server action so that it will only execute after a set delay between the fast clicks. Is that possible without having to give up on using useOptimistic?
<form
  action={async () => {
    // use useOptimistic to increment quantity state in parent
    updateQuantity(1)
    
    // server action that updates the cart with the quantity
    // if I quickly click on the increase quantity button this
    // function will be fired many times quickly. I don't want
    // the below server action to run more than eg. 300 ms after
    // THE LAST click. So how do I debounce this server action call?
    await action();
  }}
>

Someone suggested I could skip the form tag with the action attribute and even skip useOptimistic and do something like this:
const debouncedSearch = useDebounce(quantityCounter, 300); // time in ms
useEffect(() => {
  myServerAction({cartItemId: "someid", "quantity": quantityCounter}) // example execution
}, [debouncedSearch]);

Then I'd have to roll back the value manually in case the server request failed, which is why I really want to keep using useOptimistic where this is done automatically.
Any suggestions?
Using the latest Next.js 14
Attempted the following without luck:
Using onClick handler and wrapping the server action in a useDebounceCallback - while it prevents the server action from running multiple times, it also prevents useOptimistic from updating multiple times.

Did you find a good solution to this? I was having the same thing (trying to debounce the server action with optimistic updates for user input triggered by onChange on an input tag).

Yeah was pretty easy to make it work with useState, debounce and rollback on error manually. But it would be better with useOptimistic for sure, had it worked with debouncing
